# Ambiguous column in MySQL even with Alias

Tags: mysql, ambiguous

I have the following MySQL:

```
select  `car`.`ID` AS `ID`,
    `title`,`text`
    from `car` 
    LEFT JOIN `truck` as bigcar ON bigcar.`ID` = `car`.`truckID` 
    WHERE `ID` ='1';
```

For some reason I'm getting

> Column 'ID' in where clause is ambiguous

For complicated code reasons, I'm not renaming the alias as something else (such as ID2) 
Shouldn't this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the table you are using for `id` in your the where clause. Otherwise the query will know not which one to use since you have the same column name in two tables

```
SELECT
 `car`.`ID` AS `ID`, `title`,`text`
FROM `car` 
LEFT JOIN `truck` as bigcar ON bigcar.`ID` = `car`.`truckID` 
WHERE `car`.`ID` ='1';
```

or if you want the `bigcar` ID you will have to use:

```
WHERE `bigcar`.`ID` ='1'; // not truck but bigcar which is the alias you created
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
select  `car`.`ID` AS `ID`, 
    `title`,`text` 
    from `car`  
    LEFT JOIN `truck` as bigcar ON bigcar.`ID` = `car`.`truckID`  
    WHERE `car`.`ID` ='1';
```

Comment: @Martin Smith - I'm not a MySql head, but I don't get why?

Comment: er. whoops it won't convert it into an inner join at all. Comment deleted! It would have done if the where clause was on the right hand table.

Answer (score 0):

The error means the field `ID` exists in both tables. To fix it you should add a table alias to WHERE clause, e.g. - bigcar.ID = 1 or car.ID = 1 ...as you need.